# How to turn a recursive algorithm into a parallel processing recursive algorithm

Tags: c#, recursion, parallel-processing

I'm doing my homework for Algorithms and I stumbled into a problem. I was not able to transform a recursive algorithm to parallel process recursive algorithm.

**This is the given equation I was given:**

[Equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdz6f.png)

**This is my code for this equation without parallel processing:**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<int> p = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4};
        Console.WriteLine(F(4, 4, p)); 
    }

    public static int F(int k, int n, List<int> p)
    {
        List<int> maxList = new List<int>();
        int ats = 0;

        if (n == 0) { return 0; }
        else if (k == 1)
        {
            ats = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                ats += p[i];
            }
            return ats;
        }
        else
        { 
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                ats = 0;
                for (int j = i; j < n; j++)
                {
                    ats += p[j];
                }
                int funkcija = F(k - 1, n - 1, p);
                if (ats > funkcija)
                {
                    maxList.Add(ats);
                } 
                else 
                {
                    maxList.Add(funkcija);
                }
            }   
        }
        ats = maxList.Min();
        return ats;
    }
}
```

I need to make this code to process parallel. 
I tried changing for cycles into

```
I tried like this

public static int FPara(int k, int n, List<int> p)
{
    List<int> maxList = new List<int>();
    int ats = 0;

    if (n == 0) { return 0; }
    else if (k == 1)
    {
        ats = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            ats += p[i];
        }
        return ats;
    }
    else
    {
        Parallel.For(0, n - 1, i =>
        {
            ats = 0;
            for (int j = i; j < n; j++)
            {
                ats += p[j];
            }
            int funkcija = F(k - 1, n - 1, p);
            if (ats > funkcija)
            {
                maxList.Add(ats);
            }
            else
            {
                maxList.Add(funkcija);
            }
        });
    }
    ats = maxList.Min();
    return ats;
}
```

however, it doesn't work.

Comment: Please show how you tried to implement the Paralel.For

Comment: What does this algorithm do?

Comment: There is the formula in the picture.

Comment: Please write the formula out in the question, or insert the image in the body of the question using the format tools. Links can expire and it's annoying to have to look in two places to read a question.